# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 9, saw 16 but no extra data in that line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've looked around, but none of the other answers to dealing with this error have helped. I'm trying to load in a csv file, which has some junk in the first few lines and the data starts at row 4. Using:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('GRs151_1.CSV', header = 4)
```

I get:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 16
```

Strangely, as far as I can tell the offending line doesn't have excess data or anything. As a test I did:

```
with open('GRs151_1.CSV', 'r') as f:
i = 0
for line in f:
    if i < 20:
        print(i)
        try:
            a = eval(line)
            print(a)
        except:
            print('error happened')
        i += 1
```

Which outputted the expected result for all lines, including line 9:

```
0
error happened
1
error happened
2
error happened
3
error happened
4
error happened
5
(0, 0)
6
(1, 0)
7
(2, 0)
8
(3, 0)
9
(4, 0)
10
(5, 0)
11
(6, 0)
12
(7, 0)
13
(8, 0)
14
(9, 0)
15
(10, 0)
16
(11, 0)
17
(12, 0)
18
(13, 1)
19
(14, 0)
```

When I try:

```
data = pd.read_csv('GRs151_1.CSV',header = 4, usecols = (0, 1))
```

the error is now:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Not sure where to go from here besides writing a function to load in the file manually and abandon from_csv and read_csv.

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('GRs151_1.CSV', skiprows = 4) ?

Comment: Nope, same error

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without seeing the contents of the file. However, you can try to fix your issue by using a souped-up text editor like Notepad++ to view your .csv file, in order to see if there are any hidden whitespace characters, or other gnarly characters that may be messing things up for you. If you're a fan of hacky fixes you can just use the editor to get rid of the offending characters and then save. Might as well get rid of those pesky first four lines too. :)

Comment: I tried that, no special characters show up on line 9. As far as I can tell, there's no difference between it and line 8. I wrote up a quick function to load in the file, but it's very strange.